# Limit the input entered in ExtJs textfield/numberfield

Tags: extjs4

I have requirement where the `textfield/numberfield` present should only allow values between `0 to 99999.99` i.e. 5 digits with 2 decimal places.

The user should be restricted to use any invalid number.

I'm bad at regular expression but will that solve my problem ?
Any pointer to solve this issue will be appreciated.

I need to restrict user to enter any values beyond 5 digit. after 5 digit only a decimal can be placed and beyond that 2 digits

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a custom validation type [VTypes](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.VTypes).

```
addCustomVtypes : function() {
    var mRegex = /^\d{0,5}(\.\d{0,2})?$/;

    Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
        mRegex : function(val, field) {
            return ralphaNumHyphen.test(val);
        },
        mRegexText : 'Invalid input. Message here.',
        mRegexMask : /\d{0,5}(\.\d{0,2})?$/i
    });
}
```

You could call this on application launch.

Then, on your textfield, add `vtype: mRegex`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
title: 'On The Wall',
width: 300,
bodyPadding: 10,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
items: [{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    anchor: '100%',
    name: 'bottles',
    fieldLabel: 'Bottles of Beer',
    value: 0,
    maxValue: 99999.99,
    minValue: 0
}],
buttons: [{
    text: 'Take one down, pass it around',
    handler: function() {
        this.up('form').down('[name=bottles]').spinDown();
    }
}]
```

});
from:http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number

Comment: thanks for your reply ... but spindown won't solve the issue as this will bring any value that is greater than max value to be changed to the max value